# ¿Cómo indico como CommandTarget un control externo a los presentes en mi UserControl?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf, mvvm

Ya tengo tiempo intentando hacer esto y no lo consigo. Tengo un proyecto de C# en el cual estoy usando WPF para crear la interfaz y también estoy usando el modelo MVVM en el cual se estructura mi programa, tengo que cambiar entre UserControls pero al momento de indicar el comando no hay cambio alguno según yo esto es porque CommandTarget no está definido, pero cuando lo quiero definir no puedo hacer referencia a un control de la ventana en la cual se van mostrando dichos controles de usuario, específicamente este control es un ContentControl.

La pregunta sería ¿Cómo hago referencia a dicho control?

```
<Button Command="{Binding ShowRegisterCommand}"
                CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=, Mode=OneWay}"
                Style="{StaticResource labelButton}"
                Margin="0, 5, 0, 0">
            Crear Cuenta
        </Button>
```

EL código anterior es el botón que genera el cambio, pero no se que poner en ElementName para hacer referencia al ContentControl que se encuentra en mi ventana principal.

**Control al que quiero hacer el enlace**

```
<ContentControl x:Name="panelContenedor" Content="{Binding CurrentChildView}" 
                            Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Su ayuda sería de mucha utilidad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que podrías hacerlo usando RelativeSource y la etiqueta Ancestor que le indica al control que debe relacionarse a un control que está más arriba en la jerarquía dentro del etiquetado XAML.

Unos ejemplos acá, puedes probar y seguro le atinas.

```
<!-- Indica que se bindee al UserControl más proximo en la jerarquía XAML -->
<Button Command="{Binding ShowRegisterCommand}"
CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
Style="{StaticResource labelButton}"
Margin="0, 5, 0, 0">
    Crear Cuenta
</Button>

<!-- Lo mismo pero de otro modo -->
<Button Command="{Binding ShowRegisterCommand}"
CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"
Style="{StaticResource labelButton}"
Margin="0, 5, 0, 0">
    Crear Cuenta
</Button>

<!-- Indica que busque en la jerarquía el UserControl más próximo de ese tipo y se bindée-->
<Button Command="{Binding ShowRegisterCommand}"
CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
Style="{StaticResource labelButton}"
Margin="0, 5, 0, 0">
    Crear Cuenta
</Button>

<!-- Indica que busque el UserControl en una jerarquía superior ESPECÍFICA de 2 niveles hacia arriba -->
<Button Command="{Binding ShowRegisterCommand}"
CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl, AncestorLevel=2}}"
Style="{StaticResource labelButton}"
Margin="0, 5, 0, 0">
    Crear Cuenta
</Button>
```

[Más info acá](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/relativesource-markupextension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).